# What does “I”(sounds like so) called by the announcer mean during the senate leaders' vote on sb's confirmation?

Tags: word-meaning

I watched the [confirmation of Mike Pompeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKEwTUwM9t4) today online. I heard the announcer keep calling "No" or "I"(sounds like an "I") during the process.

What does that "I" stand for?

Comment: It's a rather long video. It'd be nice if we know the time in the video we can jump right to, but judging from your description, I guess it's either *Yea/Nay* or *Aye/Nay*.

Comment: @Damkerng T, the US Constitution specifies that final passage of bills depends on tallies of "yeas" and "nays," so the Senate uses those terms verbatim in certain votes. In other votes, the Senate (and the House of Representatives) use "aye" and "no."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **aye**, pronounced the same as **I**

It's an old fashioned way of saying "yes". He's recording their votes. My understanding is that it's just a tradition they have

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aye